# convert cURL to angularjs $http

Tags: angularjs, curl

I just started learning angularjs and i'm trying to get a token from an api. The curl command I have works fine when I use it in the terminal and can get the token just fine. I am having a hard time making it work using $http though.

Here's my cURL command:

```
curl --data "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_KEY&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9999&code=AUTH_CODE" https://www.twitchalerts.com/api/v1.0/token
```

Can anyone help me convert this using $http

Comment: So where's the `$http` code tried. What does your error handler tell you? What do you see in browser console when try to make request?

Comment: Just the fact that it has client secret keys in it suggests you probably can't do this with ajax anyway since it would mean exposing your credentials in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = {
    grant_type     :'authorization_code',
    client_id      :'CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret  :'SECRET_KEY',
    redirect_uri   :'http://localhost:9999&code=AUTH_CODE'
};
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
    method: 'GET',//or POST
    url: 'https://www.twitchalerts.com/api/v1.0/token',
    data:data,
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

if not then try to this

```
....
data:data,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
....
```

For more information about angular $http  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: `data` and `params` are not interchangeable for GET and POST and GET would have no contentType

Comment: @charlietfl when you submit the for whith method GET,enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded | multipart/form-data | text/plain" ,What are you think, which of these header they send? :)

Comment: Well GET has no request body so no Content Type is needed. All the data is in the url